# Was the VARIANT structure updated with unsigned short , int after visual studio 6.0

Tags: c++, com, atl

i am maintaining an old code base, which is based on COM and ATL, in one the COM ATL book i can see that the VARIANT structure does not have any unsigned data types (int or short), but the MSDN documentation shows all these defined, even the CComVariant has an overloaded operator which takes unsigned data types.

My question was this structure updated post Visual studio 6.0 ?

Comment: Hmm, no.  The oldest relevant SDK I keep around as an archeological record is the one for Win95, back when it still had the Chicago project name, dated October 1994.  VARIANT in oleaut.h back then already had VT_UI2 and VT_UI4.  So it is just the book that chose to not talk about them.

Comment: one more reason why i was curious was that Visual Basic/VBA or other automation clients do not support unsigned data types

Comment: @user2101801 that was just a shortcoming of VB6/VBA. COM itself supported them just fine.